# How To Use Time Series Functions To Generate Running Days Column From A DataFrame Date Column in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

lets say i have the following "Dates" column as the index in a trading history dataframe:

Dates

2021-01-01

2021-01-02

2021-01-03

2021-01-04

2021-01-05

2021-01-06

2021-01-07

2021-01-08

2021-01-09

2021-01-10

....

And i want to generate from this "Dates" column a running "Trading Days" column for example:

Dates                                 Trading Days

2021-01-01                            0

2021-01-02                            1

2021-01-03                            2

2021-01-04                            3

2021-01-05                            4

2021-01-06                            5

2021-01-07                            6

2021-01-08                            7

2021-01-09                            8

2021-01-10                            9

...                                            ...

Using a pandas dataframe how can this be coded?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, date

start_date = date(2021, 3, 1)
end_date = date(2021 , 3, 10)

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

dates = []
days = []
for dt in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    dates.append(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    days.append(dt.strftime("%-d"))


data = {
  "Dates": dates,
  "Trading Days": days
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
        Dates Trading Days
0  2021-03-01            1
1  2021-03-02            2
2  2021-03-03            3
3  2021-03-04            4
4  2021-03-05            5
5  2021-03-06            6
6  2021-03-07            7
7  2021-03-08            8
8  2021-03-09            9
9  2021-03-10           10
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,i think this will work!